# How can I input from user and keep in arraylist

Tags: c#

In this code, I try to code to keep customer data to keep in an array list. I need to keep first name, last name, contact number, and payment method.

```cs
public static void Rent()
{
    WriteLine("Enter your first name");
    input_fname = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter your last name");
    input_lname = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter your contact number");
    input_phone = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter your payment method");
    input_payment = ReadLine();

    ArrayList arr_cust = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr_cust.Count; i++)
    {
        arr_cust.Add(input_fname + input_lname + input_phone + input_payment);
    }

    WriteLine("Pease enter 1 to return to previous menu and 0 to exit");
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    bool exit = false;

    while (exit == false)
    {
        if (input == 1)
        {
            Main();
        }
        else if (input == 0)
        {
            WriteLine("Thank you for use Rental E-Bike System");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

My problem is when I put all of the value that i need to keep and after the I put 1 to back to main page. Next, I open Rent page again to put the second of value to keep in array list. Next step, I need to show data which I keep in array list.

Comment: I don't know if you have already studied these arguments. The answer is _not using arraylist_ but use a _class_ that defines a _Customer_ with these four _properties_ named _FirstName, LastName, Contact, PaymentMethod_ and the keep all your _Customer_ in an _List<Customer>_ (Better known as a _generic list of T_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Rent` function creates a new instance of `ArrayList` each time it is invoked and that is why `arr_cust` is always empty and the only value it has is the one you insert within the `Rent` function.

Instead of initializing `arr_cust` within `Rent` you can initialize it as a static field outside of the function so it retains the previous values.

Also you do not need the for loop to insert your data. You are inserting only once and with the for loop you are going to get N duplicates of that entry. N being the previous item count.

```cs
public static ArrayList arr_cust = new ArrayList();

public static void Rent(ArrayList arr_cust)
{
    WriteLine("Enter your first name");
    input_fname = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter your last name");
    input_lname = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter your contact number");
    input_phone = ReadLine();
    WriteLine("Enter your payment method");
    input_payment = ReadLine();

    arr_cust.Add(input_fname + input_lname + input_phone + input_payment);

    WriteLine("Pease enter 1 to return to previous menu and 0 to exit");
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());

    bool exit = false;

    while (exit == false)
    {
        if (input == 1)
        {
            Main();
        }
        else if (input == 0)
        {
            WriteLine("Thank you for use Rental E-Bike System");
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```